# JS Regex replace but skip

Tags: javascript, regex

Can you help me with some regular expression. Razor editor and I want when going through the content and find `}` to set a new order, but miss when I `}}`.

For example:

HTML file

```
<tittle> {{ title }} </title>        <-- it remains so
<script>
    function name () {
      some code...
    }                                <-- go to new line
```

My code is this:

```
    var readableHTML = text.trim();
    var lb = '\r\n';
    var tab = "\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020";

    //Check for brackets
    readableHTML = readableHTML.replace(new RegExp(" {", 'gi'), lb + tab + "{");
    readableHTML = readableHTML.replace(new RegExp("({{([^{}]*)}})([^}])", 'gi'), lb + tab + "}"); <-- This is my wrong regex
```

Comment: What is your aim: you want to prettify JavaScript code?

Comment: some thing like that yes. but i need only for this part. Tnks

Comment: Why are you using a grouping or case insensitivity?

Comment: I`m new in this thing. I try several times to make it right. I use this site to do it: https://regex101.com/r/o9Pt7s/1

Comment: Do realise that `function f() {{ return 1; }}` is valid JavaScript. What do you want to happen with that?

Comment: Noting, only to beautify the code, nothing more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to only want to add newlines before closing braces when it concerns JavaScript. I would therefore suggest you limit the scope of the replacement to the `script` tags. For that you could use a DOM parser, which will help to identify these `script` elements and allow you to alter their contents.

```js
function replaceInScripts(html, find, replace) {
    var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html,"text/html");
    Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('script'), function(script) {
        script.textContent = script.textContent.replace(find, replace);
    });
    return doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
}

// Sample data:
var html = `<html>
  <head>
    <title> {{ title }} </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        function name () { return 1; }
    <\/script>
  </body>
</html>`;

// Call the function for replacing text within script elements only:
html = replaceInScripts(html, /(\S)\s*\}/g, '$1\n    }'); 

// Output updated HTML:
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this?

```
readableHTML = readableHTML.replace(new RegExp(" \{", 'gi'), lb + tab + "{");
readableHTML = readableHTML.replace(new RegExp(" \{{2}", 'gi'), lb + tab + "{{");
readableHTML = readableHTML.replace(new RegExp(" \}", 'gi'), lb + tab + "}");
readableHTML = readableHTML.replace(new RegExp(" \}{2}}", 'gi'), lb + tab + "}}");
```